# Global variable with Vite lib mode for esm and <script /> tags

Tags: vite

I'm trying to create a library that can be used as an `esm` import as well as in a normal script tag via a global object/variable.

```
As script:

<script src="my-script.js"></script>
<script>globalObject.open()</script>

As esm:
import {globalObject} from 'my-module';
```

I'm using vite library mode

**vite.config.js**

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    copyPublicDir: false,
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "lib/main.ts"),
      formats: ["es", "umd"],
      name: "my-app",
      fileName: "my-app",
    },
  },
});
```

This produces two files in my `dist` folder.

```
my-app.js
my-app.umd.cjs
```

**Expectation**
I would expect everything I export from `main.ts` to be available as a global variable when I import the `my-app.umd.cjs` module to a script.

**Reality**
The defined exports are not available on `gloabalThis`.

I'd love some help in getting to a working setup where I have a global variable available.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution.

There is a vite.config.ts example that insert declaration of expected var in global scope:

```
export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    ... // rest of your config
    build: {
      ...
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ['react'],
        output: {
          name: YOUR_LIB_GLOBAL_ENTRY_NAME,
          globals: { 'react': 'react' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```